# phonegap plugin for eclipse, project not running in default settings

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, phonegap-plugins

```
    01-26 20:45:50.841: E/AndroidRuntime(327): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.demo.app/com.demo.app.Sencha_demoActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
01-26 20:45:50.841: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
01-26 20:45:50.841: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
01-26 20:45:50.841: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
01-26 20:45:50.841: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
01-26 20:45:50.841: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-26 20:45:50.841: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-26 20:45:50.841: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
01-26 20:45:50.841: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-26 20:45:50.841: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-26 20:45:50.841: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
01-26 20:45:50.841: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
01-26 20:45:50.841: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-26 20:45:50.841: E/AndroidRuntime(327): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
01-26 20:45:50.841: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:891)
01-26 20:45:50.841: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1865)
01-26 20:45:50.841: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.content.res.Resources.getXml(Resources.java:779)
01-26 20:45:50.841: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at com.phonegap.api.PluginManager.loadPlugins(PluginManager.java:82)
01-26 20:45:50.841: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at com.phonegap.api.PluginManager.<init>(PluginManager.java:62)
01-26 20:45:50.841: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at com.phonegap.DroidGap$1.run(DroidGap.java:414)
01-26 20:45:50.841: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:3649)
01-26 20:45:50.841: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at com.phonegap.DroidGap.loadUrlIntoView(DroidGap.java:390)
01-26 20:45:50.841: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at com.phonegap.DroidGap.loadUrl(DroidGap.java:356)
01-26 20:45:50.841: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at com.demo.app.Sencha_demoActivity.onCreate(Sencha_demoActivity.java:11)
01-26 20:45:50.841: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-26 20:45:50.841: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
01-26 20:45:50.841: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  ... 11 more
```

I am a absolute beginner to phonegap and sencha touch. After reading many forums I got this plugin for eclipse : http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/startdetails
But, when I am trying to run the project with google api 2.1 with minsdk version 7, I am getting the error mentioned above. Any ideas how to recitfy it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the res/xml/plugins.xml file from your project.

Comment: ok..i will paste it and check again then. I thought its gonna be created by the project itself by the help of plugin.

Comment: ok..now its running but not doing anything..just showing a white screen. I have tried senchas tutorial code like launch alert etc. but nothing is working.

Comment: Sorry @mad_programmer I don't have much experience with Sencha.

Comment: The white screen is the result of the example not being up to date with the latest Sencha API changes. The example was tested with Sencha 1.0.1a.

Answer (score 2):

I received a report of what is likely the same issue today and tracked it down. See [AppLaud Issue #63](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/mobile-web-development-with-phonegap/issues/detail?id=63).

The Sencha file structure changes in 2.0.0-pr4 cause the AppLaud wizard to fail to complete project creation. plugins.xml is missing and AndroidManifest.xml is not set up.

The workaround is to copy sencha-touch-all-debug-w-comments.js to sencha-touch-debug-w-comments.js and then the wizard will succeed with project completion.

This bug will be fixed in the next AppLaud update due out after the PhoneGap 1.4.0 release.

Also, note that the bundled Sencha PhoneGap example in AppLaud does not yet support the Sencha 2 APIs. See [AppLaud Issue #64](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/mobile-web-development-with-phonegap/issues/detail?id=64).